# Laravel DatabaseMigration not running migrations

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-9

I'm trying to create a very simple test, where it calls a service function that executes an `::all` function in a model.

EDIT: As mentioned in a comment, I put it as a feature test, but still same issue:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\FlashCard;
use App\Services\FlashCardService;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_the_application_returns_a_successful_response()
    {
        $flashCardService = new FlashCardService();
        $flashCardService::getAll();
    }
}
```

The `getAll()` function all it does is:

```php
public static function getAll(): Collection {
    return FlashCard::all(['id', 'question', 'answer', 'status']);
}
```

The problem is that I get an error that the is no such table
`General error: 1 no such table: flash_cards`  so the `DatabaseMigrations` is not running.

My `phpunit.xml` looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make this a feature test since you want to test with the database. Unit tests are run without database migrations.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, I changed it to a feature but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you also move the file to the tests/Feature directory?

Comment: @Coola that is not true, the only thing that matters is that the author is extending `\Tests\TestCase`, it doesn't matter in what folder it is.

Comment: @shake93 if you are using `sqlite` and `:memory:`, just use `RefreshDatabase`

Comment: Where are your migrations? Are they in the correct namespace? As suggested, you should always prefer the `RefreshDatabase` trait. As long as it's used consistently in all tests it will be much faster.

Comment: I've tried with `RefreshDatabase` and same output. Mi migrations are in database/migrations and if I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` they just run fine

Comment: It seems like if I delete the env configuration from the `phpunit.xml` it works fine, so there must be something wrong with the testing environment configuration :(